# How do I mock a jwt with Mockito

Tags: java, testing, mockito, quarkus

I have this code snippet in a controller to test in quarkus:

```
@Context 
private SecurityContext securityContext;
....
JsonWebToken jsonWebToken = (JsonWebToken) securityContext.getUserPrincipal();
if(!AuthorizationHelper.checkJwt(jsonWebToken)) {
    return Response.status(Response.Status.UNAUTHORIZED).build();
}
```

AuthorizationHelper is a class with @Singleton annotation, checkJwt() method looks like this:

```
public static boolean checkJwt(JsonWebToken jsonWebToken) {
    return jsonWebToken!=null&&jsonWebToken.getName()!=null;
}
```

And this is what I wrote:

```
@Test
public void testGetUsers() {
    Mockito.when(AuthorizationHelper.checkJwt(Mockito.any(JsonWebToken.class))).thenReturn(true);
    given()
            .when().get("/api/v1/users")
            .then()
            .statusCode(200);
}
```

It complains that "You cannot use argument matchers outside of verification or stubbing."

I did try mock SecurityContext class, and make it return a jwt I created, though I initialized that jwt, it will return null when it came securityContext.getPrincipal().

Answer (score 0):

`AuthorizationHelper.checkJwt` is a static method invocation. Mocking this works differently in mockito. As per [mockito documentation](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#48):

```
assertEquals("foo", Foo.method());
try (MockedStatic mocked = mockStatic(Foo.class)) {
    mocked.when(Foo::method).thenReturn("bar");
    assertEquals("bar", Foo.method());
    mocked.verify(Foo::method);
}
assertEquals("foo", Foo.method());
```

In your case you need to take care of the arguments and do something like this (haven't tested):

```
    mocked.when(() -> AuthorizationHelper.checkJwt(Mockito.any(JsonWebToken.class))).thenReturn(true);
```

Comment: Thank you, that actually worked, but the problem was that when the static method was called, it did not get mocked, I made it return true when get called, but it did not.